# Top-level function for onClick in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, button, onclick

Writing an Android app with Kotlin using Android Studio. I have several activities and each of them has similar buttons. I added global variable ACTID which references each Activity I have through the map.

Every button has `android: onClick="onClick"` in its XML file.

So, I tried to make a public function:

```
public fun allClick(view: View){
    val context = ACTIVITY_DICT[ACTID]
    val toast = Toast.makeText(context, ACTID.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    toast.show()
    when (view.id)
    {
        R.id.nextBtn ->    {
            val intentNext = Intent(context, ACTIVITY_DICT[ACTID+1]!!::class.java)
            context?.startActivity(intentNext)
            context?.finish()}
        R.id.backBtn ->    {
            val intentBack = Intent(context, ACTIVITY_DICT[ACTID-1]!!::class.java)
            context?.startActivity(intentBack)
            context?.finish()}
    }
}
```

However, I cannot set allCLick for `onClick`. How can I fix it? Would be grateful for any possible help.

Comment: Storing Activity references like that will leak them. You should make the `context` another parameter of the function, and then you wouldn't need the map. Have you looked at my answer to your question from yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a base activity `BaseActivity`, implement `allClick(view: View)` method in it and inherit from it other activities:

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    public fun allClick(view: View) {
        val context = ACTIVITY_DICT[ACTID]
        val toast = Toast.makeText(context, ACTID.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        toast.show()
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.nextBtn -> {
                val intentNext = Intent(context, ACTIVITY_DICT[ACTID+1]!!::class.java)
                context?.startActivity(intentNext)
                context?.finish()
            }
            R.id.backBtn -> {
                val intentBack = Intent(context, ACTIVITY_DICT[ACTID-1]!!::class.java)
                context?.startActivity(intentBack)
                context?.finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also add `android: onClick="allClick"` for every button in its XML file.